# I cannot find the difference between these wp_capabilities values in wp_usermeta

Tags: database, user-meta

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1;}

a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

I am debugging some login issues and answers online seem to use variations of these. Please explain the characters following the semicolon inside the brackets `{ ;____}`

I find these are advised for the phpMyAdmin `wp_usersmeta` table with `meta_key` for `wp_capabilities`.

Answer (score 1):

You've posted some serialized arrays.

The first entry, `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1;}` is corrupted - that's not a valid serialized array.

The second entry, `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}` looks like this when unserialized:

```
array (
  'administrator' => '1',
)
```

The third entry, `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}` looks like this when unserialized:

```
array (
  'administrator' => true,
)
```

In my setup, capabilities are stored like your third example, `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`. The underlying cause of your issue is probably related to the code that deals with how the user capabilities are being stored.